# Libgdx implementing shooting (collision between bullet and objects)

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, collision-detection

I am new to 3D programming, just started yesterday.
I am just trying to create a simple game, where i move in 3D space, but collision detection works in 2D top down space, cause my character can't jump. So collision happens only on X and Z axis.
But now i think about implementing shooting, where the bullet flies in the direction my camera is pointing (first person camera). But i have no idea how shooting is normaly implemented in 3D games? Is a `Bullet` an object, which is drawn, like in many 2D games, and moved at high speed? Or is it just a line, which isn't even shown sometimes? And how can i check for collision with that line without iterating throught all walls and mobs? I know you can find the areas throught which the bullet flies, but isn't this a big calculation when the line can go in every direction in 3D space?

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you want to show the bullet, then you can make a bullet model and make it move very fast.

These are good options each one better than the previous

- You can check for collisions iterating all the objects.
- You can have all the objects in nodes that have a reference to their neighbors and check collisions on them
- Same as previous, but you take into account the direction vector of the bullet and only check the neighbors that are in front of it.

Comment: Have you some tutorial or something for the 2nd or the 3rd solution? Thanks

Comment: Mmm I dont. But shouldnt be hard to implement. I did it with a grid, so I just used a 2d array:)

Comment: In my game i have a 2D array for all my objects (the blocks have all the same height and shappe, so no need for 3D array). But the bullet goes fast, so i have to calculate the blocks it can go throught between 2 frames. Thats my problem.

Comment: how would i calculate the "nearby objects"? I store the blocks in a 2D array, as my gamelogic is in 2D only, but the bullet can fly throught many blocks in 1 frame. So how can i calculate the first block throught which it flies in this frame?

Comment: Can you tell me how i can find the first object my bullet collides with? Lets say the bullet is a line. How can i quickly find all the tiles it flies throught without performance heavy calculations?